# Problema do DEV maior e menor de um valor

Tags: c++

Alguém pode me ajudar a consertar o comando de maior e menor basicamente ele tem que falar o maior numero de um valor e o menor numero do mesmo valor.

**Exemplo:** Eu adiciono o valor `727522` o programa vai ter que ler ele e falar que o `Maior valor é 7 e menor é 2`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <iostream>

//variaveis
int ckdig (int n, int* p, int* i)
{

//Valores nas variaveis
    int d = 0;
    if(n < 0)   n = -n;
    *p = *i = 0;

    //Par e impar
    while(n)
    {
        if((n % 2))
            (*p)++;
         else 
            (*i)++;

        n /= 10;
        d++;
    }
    return d;
}

//


inline int _abs (int n)
{
    return (n < 0) ? -n:n;
}

int digits (int val, int base)
{
    register int digs = 0, n;

    n = _abs(val);

    do
    {
        n /= base;
        digs++;
    }while(n);

    return digs;
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{


//Variaveis
    int n, p, i, d,maior=0,menor=0,num,sobra;

//Acento

(setlocale(LC_ALL,""));

//Da um Valor a n 


printf("Digite um número:");
scanf("%d", &n);

d = ckdig(n, &p, &i);


//Escreve na tela os pares e impares   


printf("Há %d pares e %d impares.\n", p, i);

//Soma


int soma;
printf("Soma de N:");soma=0;
while(n>0)
{
    soma+=n%10;
    n/=10;
}
  printf("%d\n",soma); 

// Maior e Menor 

//encontra o maior valor
    maior    = n=0;


    for (d = 1; d < n; d++) {
        if (n> maior) {
            maior    = n;
        }
    }

    //encontra o menor valor
    menor    = n=0;
    for (d = 1; d < n; d++) {
        if (n < menor) {
            menor    = n;
        }
    }


   //Escreva na tela o maior e menor numero        
  printf("Maior valor é %d e o Menor é %d ",maior,menor);
}
```

Comment: corrija a indentação de seu código, senão vai ficar difícil para outras pessoas entenderem e ajudarem...também, seja direto (mas educado) com a pergunta, não precisa pedir socorro, pedir ajuda, etc

Comment: E coloque também um titulo mais explicativo face a sua duvida. Eu por exemplo não consigo retirar nenhuma informação. O que significa exatamente "Problema do DEV" ?

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar sou novo no forum e pretendo aprender mais

Answer (score 0):

O primeiro problema é que você destruiu o valor da entrada do usuário durante o processo de soma dos dígitos, então criei uma variável auxiliar que recebe o valor da entrada.

Em seguida os processos de procura do maior e do menor dígito estão equivocados é preciso iterar sobre os dígitos para decidir o que é maior e o que é menor.

```
//Soma
int soma;
int aux = n;
printf("Soma de N:");soma=0;
while(aux > 0)
{
    soma+=aux%10;
    aux/=10; 
}
  printf("%d\n",soma); 

//encontra o maior e o menor valor
maior = 0;
menor = 10;
aux = n;

do 
{
     int d = aux%10;         
     if (d > maior) maior = d;
     if (d < menor) menor = d;
} while (aux/=10);
```

Seu código rodando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/LivelySeveralParallelprocessing)

Comment: Obrigado vou tentar

Comment: Obrigado de verdade vc abriu minha mente de vdd